# Separate Entity from Model or keep them as one class (SpotORM)

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, php-di

I am progressively incorporating in my project an ORM (with SpotORM) and dependency injection (with PHP-DI) and I want to do it right. Right now I can't figure out if the Entity and the Model are supposed to be two different classes, or just one.

The Entity class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Entity;

use Spot\Entity as Entity;

class Person extends Entity
{
    protected static $table = "t_person";

    public static function fields()
    {
        return [
            "id" => ["type" => "integer", "primary" => true, "autoincrement" => true],
            "firstname" => ["type" => "string", "length" => 50],
            "lastname" => ["type" => "string", "length" => 50],
        ];
    }
}
```

This gives me access to `firstname` with `$person->get("firstname")` or `$person->getFirstname()`.

I want to create a method `getFullName()` which returns the first name followed by the last name. My first thought was to write it in this entity class, which works great.

Now I want to use dependency injection for a method like getSlug(), using a Slugifier which comes from a library. But I can't inject it in the constructor because it has a specific signature and is called by SpotORM only.

So I thought I need to have a separate class to put my methods into, but then the ORM doesn't know about it, and for example if I get a list of Person entities from a Organization entity, via a relation, I don't have my additional methods.

What is the usual way to go about this?

Comment: I'm unable to create the [spotorm] tag (1500+ rep. needed), feel free to add it if you can.

Comment: The terms `Entity` and `Model` are synonym. The method `getFullName` fits perfectly in the entity.  Slug generation doesn't belong to the entity and should be done in your service or controller. Something like `Slugifier::getSlug($person->getFullName());` which could be used anywhere in you code.

Comment: @SanderVisser Thank you. So my entity can't have any dependency? If I want to `sendMail()` on an `User`, I guess I need to instanciate a `Mailer` manually in the controller? If I want to use a cache to avoid fetching data from the database if it had been already, I can't use it in the entity's methods?

Comment: An entity should never have dependencies. To send a mail, you indeed should inject an `Mailer` instance which you then could use in your controller as example. The ORM itself, that retrieves the data from the database and fills your entity. and should also handle the caching/optimizations for you not the entity itself

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm good to go with this! Too bad there's no answer to accept!